# Adding Scala to `PATH` in Zsh

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, zsh

I have downloaded Scala to `~/bin` for easy access on my machine; but I seem to have some difficulty adding it to the `PATH`.

On my MacBook I simply added the following to `~/.profile` and everything just worked:

```bsh
SCALA_HOME=$HOME/bin/scala-2.11.7
PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

On my Linux box however, I've tried putting the same code in both `~/.profile` and `~/.zshrc`, and it still doesn't correctly display `/home/coffee/bin/scala-2.11.7/bin/scala` when running `which scala`.

`source .zshrc` doesn't work at all, and `source .profile` only works until I re-open the console (I put the code into both just in case).

So what am I doing wrong here, and how do I get it to work?

Comment: Sounds like you are using Elementary OS.  Elementary OS is off topic here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThomasW. does that even really matter? it's ubuntu-based and got the same exact internals; add to that zsh runs on both

Comment: If it displayed `/Users/coffee/bin/scala-2.11.7/bin/scala` I'd be amazed. This isn't OSX, whatever Linux distro you maybe using. And questions on elementary OS belong on [unix.se] or [elementaryos.se].

Comment: @muru and why would you be amazed? all it should do is echo the path; which it correctly does when sourcing the profile

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Yes it does matter.  They make changes that make it different from Ubuntu and it is not supported by Ubuntu.  We only support official Ubuntu derivatives and flavors as outlined in the Help Center here.

Comment: Because neither elementary OS nor Ubuntu typically has home directories in `/Users`, they typically use `/home/`. If you're using a common home directory on OSX and Linux, well, who knows what else is going wrong with your shell configuration.

Comment: @muru right, brainfart ocurred. It does display home, I just didn't look properly. Doesn't change the fact that it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `PATH` is not sourced from `~/.profile` has 2 very good reasons behind it:

1. Only login shells source `~/.profile`. So that's not expected to be sourced in a normal terminal. If you're unable to get it to work in a login shell that's because
2. Zsh sources `~/.zprofile`, not `~/.profile`.

The fact that the changes are lost after sourcing `~/.profile` is expected, since what is sourced affects only the current shell; that's why `~/.profile` / `~/.zprofile` are sourced each time the shell starts.

The fact that it works when sourcing `~/.profile` and not when sourcing `~/.zshrc` is apparently unexplainable.

My guess is that an `export` / `source` is messing with `PATH` later / you're just running the wrong commands in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I wonder, could it be because it exports path by default somewhere within the file? causing it to overwrite the changes

Comment: @ElectricCoffee That may *well* be, I assumed you were sure that's wasn't happening. `grep '^\(source\|export\)' ~/.bashrc` to quickly see the chain of `source`s / `export`s.

Comment: I did a `cat .zshrc | grep PATH` and lo and behold, it did already define an export. That was the bug after all. But thanks for the explanation anyway